# Find median of list of images

Tags: image, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, image-processing

If I have a list of images represented by 3D ndarray such as `[[x,y,color],...]`, what operations can I use to output an image with values that are median of all values? I am using a for loop and find it too slow.

Comment: Share your loopy implementation that produces the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said your images in color, formatted as a list of 3d `ndarrays`. Let's say there are `n` images:

```
imgs = [img_1, ..., img_n]
```

Where imgs is a `list` and each `img_i` is a an `ndarray` with shape `(nrows, ncols, 3)`.

Convert the list to a 4d ndarray, then take the median over the dimension that corresponds to images:

```
import numpy as np

# Convert images to 4d ndarray, size(n, nrows, ncols, 3)
imgs = np.asarray(imgs)

# Take the median over the first dim
med = np.median(imgs, axis=0)
```

This gives the pixel-wise median. The value of each color channel of each pixel is the median of the corresponding pixel/channel in all images.

The documentation for `asarray()` says "no copy is performed if the input is already an ndarray". This suggests that the operation would be faster if you stored the original list of images as a 4d `ndarray` instead of a list. In that case, it wouldn't be necessary to copy the information in memory (or to run `asarray()`)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried axis=0 earlier and it did not work. Tried again and code `np.median(imgs, axis=0)` is simple and works.

Answer (score 7):

This is my vectorized implementation using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

For my test I used these five images:

[image]

The relevant parts:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

# Load five images:
ims = [scipy.ndimage.imread(str(i + 1) + '.png', flatten=True) for i in range(5)]
# Stack the reshaped images (rows) vertically:
ims = np.vstack([im.reshape(1,im.shape[0] * im.shape[1]) for im in ims])
# Compute the median column by column and reshape to the original shape:
median = np.median(ims, axis=0).reshape(100, 100)
```

The complete script:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ims = [scipy.ndimage.imread(str(i + 1) + '.png', flatten=True) for i in range(5)]
print ims[0].shape # (100, 100)

ims = np.vstack([im.reshape(1,im.shape[0] * im.shape[1]) for im in ims])
print ims.shape # (5, 10000)

median = np.median(ims, axis=0).reshape(100, 100)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100./109., 100./109.), dpi=109, frameon=False)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')
plt.imshow(median, cmap='Greys_r')
plt.show()
```

The median (`numpy.median`) result of the five images looks like this:

[image]

Fun part: The mean (`numpy.mean`) result looks like this:

[image]

Okay, science meets art. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Can you put an example of your data ?

Else, I think that you could maybe use numpy with `numpy.mean` ?

You have the doc [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) ;)

Comment: OP explicitly asked for median not mean.