# Efficient way to compute the median of an array of canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, glsl, median

I have an array of `N` HTMLCanvasElements that come from N frames of a video, and I want to compute the "median canvas" in the sense that every component (r, g, b, opacity) of every pixel is the median of the corresponding component in all the canvases.

The video frames are 1280x720, so that the pixels data for every canvas (obtained with `canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data`) is a Uint8ClampedArray of length 3.686.400.

The naive way to compute the median is to:

- prepare a result Uint8ClampedArray of length 3.686.400
- prepare a temporary Uint8ClampedArray of length N
- loop from 0 to 3.686.399

  - a) loop over the N canvases to fill the array
  - b) compute the median of the array
  - c) store the median to the result array

But it's very slow, even for 4 canvases.

Is there an efficient way (or existing code) to do that? My question is very similar to [Find median of list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444436/find-median-of-list-of-images), but I need to to this in JavaScript, not Python.

Note: for b), I use [d3.median()](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/#median) which doesn't work on typed arrays, as far as I understand, so that it implies converting to numbers, then converting back to Uint8Clamped.

Note 2: I don't know much of GLSL shaders, but maybe [using the GPU](https://gist.github.com/kitasenjudesign/5c1818585753d6d690e69a7b5c67da95) would be a way to get faster results. It would require to [pass data from the CPU to the GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440389/how-to-write-a-fragment-shader-in-glsl-to-sort-an-array-of-9-floating-point-numb#comment38181327_19440389) though, which takes time if done repeatedly.

Note 3: the naive solution is there: https://observablehq.com/@severo/compute-the-approximate-median-image-of-a-video

Comment: The whole issue reminds me of an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you sure that calculating the median for all pixel data will fix the underlying problem? It may be worth taking a step back to see the bigger picture instead of trying to fix a non-optimal solution.:What are you trying to achieve with that median? Are there alternative approaches to the problem? Using the mean—i.e. `d3.mean()`—instead is lighting fast as compared to the median. It's a compromise, though, as it is more easily skewed by extreme values. Still, it's fast...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right, my X problem is not to have a median image of the video, but to have an image of the "scene background" (the road) without the "moving parts" (the cars). The median of all the frames normally gives approximately what I want, but there could be other options, sure, and I should review the litterature.

Comment: Note that I'm also interested in the problem _per se_: it seems to be computationally hard, and I wonder if this is the kind of problem where GPU can help, or if it's not easy to parallelize due to the sorting step.

Comment: I just put together an answer suggesting a solution to your Y-problem. That might already do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> I use `d3.median()` which doesn't work on typed arrays…

Although that is not exactly true it leads into the right direction. Internally [`d3.median()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/median.js) uses the [`d3.quantile()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/quantile.js) method which starts off like this:

```js
export default function quantile(values, p, valueof) {
  values = Float64Array.from(numbers(values, valueof));
```

As you can see, this in fact does make use of typed arrays, it is just not your [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) but a [`Float64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array) instead. Because floating-point arithmetic is much more computation-intensive than its integer counterpart (including the conversion itself) this has a dramatic effect on the performance of your code. Doing this some 3 million times in a tight loop kills the efficiency of your solution.

Since you are retrieving all your pixel values from a `Uint8ClampedArray` you can be sure that you are always dealing with integers, though. That said, it is fairly easy to build a custom `function median(values)` derived from `d3.median()` and `d3.quantile()`:

```js
function median(values) {
  // No conversion to floating point values needed.
  if (!(n = values.length)) return;
  if (n < 2) return d3.min(values);
  var n,
      i = (n - 1) * 0.5,
      i0 = Math.floor(i),
      value0 = d3.max(d3.quickselect(values, i0).subarray(0, i0 + 1)),
      value1 = d3.min(values.subarray(i0 + 1));
  return value0 + (value1 - value0) * (i - i0);
}
```

On top of getting rid of the problematic conversion on the first line this implementation additionally applies some more micro-optimizations because in your case you are always looking for the 2-quantile (i.e. the median). That might not seem much at first, but doing this multiple million times in a loop it does make a difference.

With minimal changes to your own code you can call it like this:

```js
// medianImageData.data[i] = d3.median(arr);   Instead of this use line below.
medianImageData.data[i] = median(arr);
```

Have a look at my working [fork](https://observablehq.com/@altocumulus/compute-the-approximate-median-image-of-a-video) of your Observable notebook.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's totally usable with these optimizations! Thanks for the code, the notebook fork and the explanation, that's a great answer.

Comment: Note that you can "suggest" a notebook merge in Observable (https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/fork-share-merge).